# What is limiting the size of my logo in phpbb?

Tags: css, phpbb

Hello I am currently teaching myself php, and I am having trouble with the logo at the top of my page. I have checked my CSS a couple of times, but clearly this setting is beyond my knowledge. The banner should be 952 pixels wide and its not.

http://omnigame.tv/forums/

You can see the banner is cut in half. Thought the problem was in this code. Could be wrong though:

```
#logo {
float: left;
width: auto;
padding: 10px 13px 0 10px;
}
```

Tried changing width to the size I wanted didnt work

Also tried this one:

```
.logo {
background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/logo.png");
width: 952px;
height: 117px;
margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Changing either of them still resulted in a bad banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got two elements limiting the size of the banner `.logo` as you suggest above, but also `.logo-bg` which is currently:

```
.logo-bg {
    background-image: url("./styles/darkfx/theme/images/logo-bg.png");
    width: 523px;
    height: 117px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Remove the width restriction from that *and* `.logo` and you get the full image.

Comment: I'm guessing there is another .logo-bg because I currently have its width set to 952 in darkfx.css
Is there something out there to search within files? As I said I am self teaching myself this stuff so my knowledge is fairly limited in some aspects

Comment: It's in "style.php" - included from line 76 of your main file. (If you're using/can use Google Chrome its `Inspect Element` feature is really useful for finding and fixing this sort of problem.)

Comment: Ok I see how to use that it does show that the banner is still 351 x 117. However .logo is not defined in style.php from what I can see. I found it on a couple style sheets where I changed the width again. But it changed nothing on the page

And I can see with developer tools that if I were to change the value from 351 to 952 it would fix all my problems. But even after changing it in the CSS I could find the .logo in it remamins unchanged.

Comment: It's `.logo-bg` in style.php, not `.logo`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D1nqUd8Z

There is neither in that. There is the whole style.php.

There is no .logo or .logo-bg

which is why im confused.

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry. wasn't allowing for the fact that style.php was dynamically creating the stylesheet. From the looks of the code phpBB is bringing in a few styles from the directory `styles/{$theme['theme_path']}/theme` where $theme['theme_path'] will be the one you've configured in the ACP - I'm guessing either `prosilver` or `darkfx`.